# how does the rails cache proxy can store private caches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

as we now, when it comes to "http caching system", we have two kind of caches: public and private and their difference is all about proxies existing between user and the server. proxies cannot store private caches.
in [this](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_1-caching_strategies/) link, he talks about rack:cache calling it a kind of proxy cache and he says:

> This means it cannot cache private content but it can cache public
>   content.

but in the examples(even his examples) and in the reality, we see that by using `stale` or `fresh_when`(which use rack::cache) the private caches are stored and then rendered by 304.

so we confronted to a paradox. how did this rack:cache proxy store the private caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `stale?` or `fresh_when?`,  `rack::cache` is using that information to tell the client whether its cache it fresh or not. `rack::cache` is not caching the content.

A cache, if marked as private, can only be stored by the final user. But whether that cache is fresh or not can be determined by a proxy, like `rack:cache`.